# Eclipse doesn't recognize custom classes despite correct setup

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, package

I have the following setup in my project:

```
com.foo
 - Main
com.foo.util
 - StringUtil
```

In `Main` I import the `StringUtil` using

```
package com.foo;
import com.foo.util.StringUtil;
```

And use it just as you would use it;

```
StringUtil string = new StringUtil();
```

Yet, eclipse keeps telling me that *StringUtil cannot be resolved to a type* - how can this be?

I already tried refreshing the project, reimporting it as a new project, clicked through the build paths but everything seems to be set up correctly.

But still, eclipse doesn't recognize the class and won't compile my project.

Comment: com.foo.util
 - StringUtil
so import com.foo.util.StringUtil;

Comment: @Florian Peschka : Try to shutdown your Eclipse and restart again, then immediately refresh the project as fast as it started. Some say it's a bug, that can happen sometimes, not sure though, how much will it help. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was due to some messed up eclipse installation.

Wiping the project, checkout it again and reimport it in a restarted eclipse solved every issue.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: The original question had this format:

```
package com.foo;
import com.foo.StringUtil;
```

Thus my answer was:

Because `StringUtil` is in `com.foo.util` and not in `com.foo`.

Change it to `import com.foo.util.StringUtil`.

Comment: Yeah, well... that's why I `import com.foo.util` in my `Main`, isn't it?

Comment: Well spotted. And as an extra tip: use one of the wonderful features of Eclipse called "Organize Imports".

Comment: @FlorianPeschka : As said in the question you mentioned that you imported import com.foo.StringUtil; not import com.foo.util.StringUtil; +1 for good catch.  Regards

Comment: "that's why I import com.foo.util in my Main,"
What I'm saying is - that is what you think you are doing. A good look at the code reveals that you made a mistake there. (Also, I don't think I ever heard of importing packages like that - I'm used to `import com.foo.util.*`!)

Comment: Argh, sorry... I posted the question wrong - Of course I import from `com.foo.util` -- And organize imports changes it to `com.foo.util.*` but the problem still remains.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and closing and restarting Eclipse?

Comment: So, I actually had to wipe the complete project, check it out again and import it as a new project on a freshly started eclipse. Now it's fine again... thanks for all your participation

Answer (score 2):

Use CTRL + SHIFT + O shortcut to organize imports automatically. It will save your time.

Answer (score 2):

Can be a typo, but in your import it says `import com.foo.StringUtil;`, but shoud be `import com.foo.util.StringUtil;` try press Ctrl-1 (Quick fix) when class is in focus. This gives suggestions on errors

Comment: +1, I didn't knew that, might will help me too sometime soon. Hehe :-) Regards

Answer (score 1):

Is your class public (Which I believe it is if you can import it) with default constructor there if there are overriden constructor and otherwise no overridden constructor + constructor being public?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the project to a new project solves this issue.